# Deployment fails without prompting any errors on console on digitalocean app-engine django app

Tags: python, django, docker, digital-ocean

We have 2 apps that are running with similar settings, now we are trying to deploy another app but this time it's failing without telling any error in app engine. Python django app starts and then suddenly app engine stops deployment. How to find reason behind that?

```
2023-01-10T04:22:27.009643496Z Operations to perform:
2023-01-10T04:22:27.009843250Z   Apply all migrations: accounts, admin, auth, authtoken, contenttypes, sessions
2023-01-10T04:22:27.025117275Z Running migrations:
2023-01-10T04:22:27.025132491Z   No migrations to apply.
2023-01-10T04:22:28.914809605Z [2023-01-10 04:22:28 +0000] [3] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2023-01-10T04:22:28.916522026Z [2023-01-10 04:22:28 +0000] [3] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (3)
2023-01-10T04:22:28.916664847Z [2023-01-10 04:22:28 +0000] [3] [INFO] Using worker: uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker
2023-01-10T04:22:28.977228185Z [2023-01-10 04:22:28 +0000] [4] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 4
2023-01-10T04:22:30.789477002Z [2023-01-10 04:22:30 +0000] [4] [INFO] Started server process [4]
2023-01-10T04:22:30.789716598Z [2023-01-10 04:22:30 +0000] [4] [INFO] Waiting for application startup.
2023-01-10T04:22:30.790170632Z [2023-01-10 04:22:30 +0000] [4] [INFO] ASGI 'lifespan' protocol appears unsupported.
2023-01-10T04:22:30.790507246Z [2023-01-10 04:22:30 +0000] [4] [INFO] Application startup complete.
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you missed assigning the correct port for that specific app. By default DO sets port 8080. And according to logs, it's listening to port 5000.

```
2023-01-10T04:22:28.916522026Z [2023-01-10 04:22:28 +0000] [3] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (3)
```

So probably that could be the mistake. You can update it from the YAML file in the digital ocean app settings.
Or click the edit icon corresponding to the resource to configure details such as HTTP routes or the HTTP port.